# Linking MySQL server to MS SQL server

Tags: loading

I have a requirement to access my sql server db from ms sql,keep updating those tables data into ms sql database almost daily.I tried doing this using linked servers.

I have used ODBC administrator v 5.3 for it and the driver 'My SQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI driver' and i have set up the connection and tested,which worked fine.I have added the mysql db to the linked server with the following command

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'MYSQL', 
@srvproduct=N'MySQL', 
@provider=N'MSDASQL', 
@provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=10.36.45.10; _ 
DATABASE=tigerdb; USER=casklgh; PASSWORD=hejsan; OPTION=3'
```

After creating,when i expand the linked server tree,I am not able to access tables and views.I am getting error

Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL". 
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MYSQL" returned message

Please suggest what can be done

Thank you

Comment: Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. I tried doing the same by doing remote desktop to the server and done the whole process on the server and it worked fine.:)

Comment: i know it's been a while, but i am actually facing the same issue now, so you had both MSSQL and MySQL on the same server to get it done? is that correct?